# how to output forward slash

Tags: php, json, variables

I have simple problem trying to figure out.

I needs to get output to echo url address like this.

```
"image": "http://test.info/json/movies/1.jpg"
```

i'm trying stuck with this code

```
<?php
include_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$products = $db->getAllProducts();
$a = array();
$b = array();
$c = 'test.info/json/movies/';
if ($products != false){
    $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($products);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($products)) {       


        $b["image"] = $c.''.$row["photo"];



        array_push($a,$b);
    }
    echo json_encode($a);
}
```

?>

Currently i'm getting json output as following.

```
"image":"http:\/\/test.info\/json\/movies\/uploadsimage0214.png"
```

please help me to get rid of extra backslashes.

Comment: use option - `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES (integer)
Don't escape /. Available since PHP 5.4.0.` - http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: thanks you it worked.. :)
here is is my solution.
echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Answer (score 0):

You can either use str_replace(); or just just the flag `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as

```
echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```